# Why are my scrollbars not appearing?

Tags: html, css

I am desining a template that has a header with a logo on the top, and a container.  In the container is a vertical navigation menu on the left side, a horizontal nav menu on top, and a content area in the remaining container space. I want the vertical nav menu to have a scrollbar(working) and the content area to have a scrollbar(not working).  I don't want a scroll bar on the horizontal nav menu. The entire inner container is fixed which is why I want the scrollbars.  Why are the scrollbars not showing?  In the jsFiddle, the pink area should have the vertical scrollbars.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm7x6sbw/).

This is my CSS:

```css
body {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #CCC;
}

a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#container-outer {
  margin: 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

#logo {
  background: #000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 32px auto;
  width: 427px;
  height: 66px;
}

#container-inner {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  left: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
  height: calc(100% - 130px - 32px);
}

nav#navigation_primary {
  background: red;
  width: 15%;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: white;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #222222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/shadow_horizontal.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 18px 18px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul li a:hover {
  background: #d28c17;
  color: #333;
}

nav#navigation_secondary {
  height: 66px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(85% - 1px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  float: left;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 66px;
  line-height: 66px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/shadow_vertical.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #222222;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul li a:hover {
  background: #d28c17;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #d28c17;
  margin: 0px;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #111111;
  border: 1px solid #222222;
  margin-top: 24px;
  color: #666;
}

table {
  margin: 16px 0px;
}

table tr td {
  background: #111111;
  padding: 8px;
}

main {
  background: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: calc(85% - 33px);
  min-height: 150%;
}

.row [class^="col-"]:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.row [class^="col-"]:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-outer">
  <div id="logo">Logo Here</div>
  <div id="container-inner">
    <nav id="navigation_primary">
      <h3>Nav Title</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="navigation_secondary">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="panel">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <table align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main` element will increase its size for every child it has and `#container-inner` will overflow the size of `main`, therefore, `main` will never have the scroll because it doesn't have a `max-height`.

## Solution

Fix the height of `main` to:

- `#container-inner` - `#navigation_secondary` - margin of `main` (top and bottom `16px`)
- `100% - 66px - 32px`

---

***[See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm7x6sbw/5/)***

---

```
main {
  background: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 16px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(85% - 33px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 66px - 32px);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #CCC;
}

a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#container-outer {
  margin: 32px;
  padding: 0;
}

#logo {
  background: #000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 32px auto;
  width: 427px;
  height: 66px;
}

#container-inner {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  left: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
  height: calc(100% - 130px - 32px);
}

nav#navigation_primary {
  background: red;
  width: 15%;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: white;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #222222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/shadow_horizontal.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 18px 18px 0px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav#navigation_primary ul li a:hover {
  background: #d28c17;
  color: #333;
}

nav#navigation_secondary {
  height: 66px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(85% - 1px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  float: left;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 66px;
  line-height: 66px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/shadow_vertical.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #222222;
}

nav#navigation_secondary ul li a:hover {
  background: #d28c17;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #d28c17;
  margin: 0px;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #111111;
  border: 1px solid #222222;
  margin-top: 24px;
  color: #666;
}

table {
  margin: 16px 0px;
}

table tr td {
  background: #111111;
  padding: 8px;
}

main {
  background: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 16px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(85% - 33px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 66px - 32px);
}

.row [class^="col-"]:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.row [class^="col-"]:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.no-gutters > .col,
.no-gutters > [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-10,
.col-11,
.col-12,
.col,
.col-auto,
.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm,
.col-sm-auto,
.col-md-1,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md,
.col-md-auto,
.col-lg-1,
.col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-5,
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7,
.col-lg-8,
.col-lg-9,
.col-lg-10,
.col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12,
.col-lg,
.col-lg-auto,
.col-xl-1,
.col-xl-2,
.col-xl-3,
.col-xl-4,
.col-xl-5,
.col-xl-6,
.col-xl-7,
.col-xl-8,
.col-xl-9,
.col-xl-10,
.col-xl-11,
.col-xl-12,
.col-xl,
.col-xl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.col {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.col-auto {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.col-1 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  max-width: 8.333333%;
}

.col-2 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
  max-width: 16.666667%;
}

.col-3 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
}

.col-5 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
  max-width: 41.666667%;
}

.col-6 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  max-width: 58.333333%;
}

.col-8 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
  max-width: 66.666667%;
}

.col-9 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 75%;
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
  max-width: 83.333333%;
}

.col-11 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
  max-width: 91.666667%;
}

.col-12 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-outer">
  <div id="logo">Logo Here</div>
  <div id="container-inner">
    <nav id="navigation_primary">
      <h3>Nav Title</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="navigation_secondary">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="panel">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <table align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you scroll are not appearing because you are using  **min-height** here which will never allow overflow:scroll use **height:100%** instead here

**you Problem**

```
.main {
  background: pink;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: calc(85% - 33px);
  min-height: 150%;
}
```

**my solution**

```
   .main {
      background: pink;
      overflow-y: auto;
      margin: 16px;
      padding: 0;
      float: left;
      width: calc(85% - 33px);
      height: 100%;
    }
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pm7x6sbw/3/)

Comment: Ok, so that got the scrollbar to appear, but it doesn't let me scroll down all the way.  If you scroll to the bottom of the scroll bar, inspect the last link you see, you will see that there are two additional table rows that aren't visible.

Comment: in That case just decrease Height upto **72%** or depends upon your choice where it fits for you

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `main` class has no fixed `height`, only a `min-height`. A container needs a fixed size in order to have overflowing content.

> **Note**: The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

How your CSS should look

```
   .main {
      background: pink;
      overflow-y: auto;
      margin: 16px;
      padding: 0;
      float: left;
      width: calc(85% - 33px);
      height: 85%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container-inner {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  left: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
  height: calc(100% - 130px - 32px);
}
```

You want `overflow: auto;`.  `hidden` means it will always be hidden no matter what.

Comment: The `container-inner` class is not used in his content area. Look at the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

it because you needed to change your height i took liberty of changing one of them by using:

```
 height: 1000px;
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm7x6sbw/2/)